# How to Determine the Correct Size of Beam to Support Suspended Planter

Tags: woodworking, structural

I am trying to plan a project that will look like this. [image: suspended planter diagram]

The bottom piece will be secured down and won't be able to move. I'm trying to figure out what size of beam I will need to connect the bottom piece to the top piece without being worried about it falling down. I don't have exact dimensions as I'm still trying to figure out if this is doable. The whole thing will be mounted inside of a garden window that sticks out of the house. The window is about a foot deep and the whole contraption will probably be around 3 feet wide. It will be used to house plants, so it will have soil, but shouldn't be very much. If possible, I'd like a general formula or method to make sure the connecting pieces will hold.

Comment: I can get dimensions when I get home tonight or add another picture if necessary.

Comment: Yes this is doable assuming reasonable dimensions, weight load, and sizing of beams & boxes. In addition to sizing the beams, you also need strong connections between the beams and boxes, and between the lower box and whatever it's secured to. Will this be standing on the ground or hanging off a ledge? If it's accessible, you should also consider how it would handle a person doing something dumb like climbing on it. You may also need to consider wind and snow load. In any case, some better idea of how big it is, what's in it, and where it's installed would help people provide some guidance.

Comment: I edited the question to have more details. Let me know if you need more info.